# Android decoding json response

Tags: android, exception, json

the request processing code

```
  while($op=db_fetch_object($result))
  {
    $data[$i++]=array($op->name,$op->age,$op->dept);
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
```

$data contains

> [["Aadidev","23","division1"],["Ragman","35","division3"],["Sahlaad","27","division1"],["Maraadhak","21","division2"],["Arya","48","division1"],["Shank","25","division1"],["Aatmaj","54","division1"],["Abhay","46","division2"],["Bhinatha","37","division2"],["Abhineet","29","division3"],["Srita","47","division1"]]

Android code

```
String nameop="";
 try{
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(page);
    JSONArray namearr=json.names();
    JSONArray valarr=json.toJSONArray(namearr);
    for(int i=0;i<valarr.length();i++)
    {
     nameop+=namearr.getString(i)+" "+valarr.getString(i)+"\n";
    }
    result.setText(nameop);
    }catch(Exception e){
     Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

which results an exception

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject
>   text must begin with '{' at character 1
>   of
>   [["Aadidev","23","division1"],["Ragman","35","division3"],["Sahlaad","27","division1"],["Maraadhak","21","division2"],["Arya","48","division1"],["Shank","25","division1"],["Aatmaj","54","division1"],["Abhay","46","division2"],["Bhinatha","37","division2"],["Abhineet","29","division3"],["Srita","47","division1"]].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` to force creation of an object.

Just using json_encode() on an array doesn't generate an object, which Java's JSONObject seems to assume.

this is PHP >= 5.3!

Answer (score 0):

Your json string should indeed begin with a '{' character.  Try parsing the string from within your php app and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your php code a bit:

while($op=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(your query)))
  {
       
$data[$i]["name"]= $op["name"];
   
$data[$i]["age"]= $op["age"];
   
$data[$i]["dept"]= $op["dept"];
   
$i++;
  }

echo json_encode($data);

This will return a json string like: 
[{"name":"name1","age":"age1","dept":"dept1"},{"name":"name2","age":"age2","dept":"dept2"}]

Then you need to parse this json string in java code

Comment: I have slightly changed the code above try it using this way........ also try what " Zoran Zaric " has told

Comment: the java json parser seems to expect a "{" as the first character, so it won't accept "your" json string.

Comment: This will create problem if we use JSONObject, JSONObject expects first character as "{". But my string is a type of an array of JSONObject, so in this case one will have to use JSONArray and loop through each object.     Thanks..............